# Add version information to product of RCP application

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

Hi I want to add the current Version (manually defined in the parent pom) of my RCP Application in an "About" section which means I need to access it during runtime. What is the default way to do that for a pomless maven tycho build? I tried the properties-maven-plugin but have problems combining the properties file with my build. So I guess there has to be a more convenient way. Thanks you for any help!

Comment: The default way is the [maven-resources-plugin](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/pom.xml#L76-L102) with an [about.mappings](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/ea6960e6ee6c31ef96ec12c34d8f94e7ab0e40dd/org.idealized.customization/about.mappings) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse itself uses the [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://github.com/eclipse-packaging/packages/blob/af613f432c090a51ddafb12dcc7238f8b70f140a/releng/org.eclipse.epp.config/parent/bundle/pom.xml#L49-L74) to add version information to the [`about.mappings`](https://github.com/eclipse-packaging/packages/blob/af613f432c090a51ddafb12dcc7238f8b70f140a/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java/about.mappings) file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-about.mappings</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>about.mappings</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```